# How to add a facebook page's events to website

Tags: magento, facebook-graph-api, google-calendar-api, magento2

I'm looking for a solution to get a list of events from a public page on Facebook to display on my website in a list.  I'm using Magento 2 for the website.  I know there are Facebook widgets, Facebook login capabilities, etc.  I don't want any of that.  I am not looking to integrate Facebook, I just want a list of the publicly viewable events so I can put them on my website.  I don't want events for a user, I want the business page's events.  This seems like it should be a straight forward thing but I can't seem to find anything that does this.

Alternatively, I've heard you can integrate Google Calendar to create events in Facebook, and I could integrate Google Calendar into my website.  That seems a bit more convoluted as the social admins prefer to create events in Facebook, but I'll take what I can get.  If this method is the best way, can you point me in the right direction?  Are there libraries to use, etc?

Thanks!

Comment: There currently is no API access to page events for normal 3rd-party apps, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're correct, you can integrate Google Calendar to Facebook and you can also embed a calendar in your Facebook Page. You don't need to code the integration, you can just follow the steps provided from this [blog](https://strategybykatie.com/add-google-calendar-apptab-facebook/).

Here are the steps you on how to add your Google Calendar to your Facebook Page:

> - Open up your Facebook Page
> - In a separate tab open up your Google calendar
> - Click on the cog in the upper right-hand corner, and select “Settings”
> - Click on “Calendars”
> - Click on the calendar you want to add to your Facebook Page
> - You should see the embed code here (If you want to make any color changes or style changes you will need to do it before adding it to
>     your Facebook Page)
> - Select all the code and copy it to your clipboard
> - In another tab open this link: Static HTML: iframe tabs
> - Click “Add Static HTML to a Page”
> - Select the page you want to add a new tab to from the drop-down menu
> - Next click “Add Page Tab”
> - Once your page has refreshed, click “Set up tab”
> - Select all the text in the app editor, and delete it
> - Paste the code that you copied from your Google calendar
> - In the upper right-hand corner click “Save and Publish”
> - Refresh your Facebook Page and check out your new tab